# Mutate not functioning

Tags: r

I have spent all day trying every possible permutation of mutate I can think of or find examples of to no effect.  All I am trying to do is break apart the date so that I can create a chart from an excel spreadsheet. I want plot counts against month and week and day.  It seems so simple but just seems not to be sticking. The spreadsheet is in the form of date Y-M-D with additional columns with numbers with headers like chat, email

The error says

```
Error in mutate(., Date = Date %>% as.character %>% ymd) : 
  is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE

require(shiny)
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
library(plyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
# load data:

oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref2.csv")
log <- log %>%
    mutate(Date = Date %>% as.character %>% ymd) 

# glimpse function from dplyr is similar to str but specifically designed for tibbles and dplyr

glimpse(log) 



# create variables of the week and month of each observation:
log$Month <- as.Date(cut(log$date,
                         breaks = "month"))
log$Week <- as.Date(cut(log$Date,
                       breaks = "week",
                       start.on.monday = FALSE)) # changes weekly break point to Sunday
log$Day <- as.Date(cut(log$Date,
                       breaks = "day"))
                       
log




ui <- fluidPage(
    
    
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("selUI")
        ),
        
        
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    
    output$selUI = renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "varSel",
                    label = "Transaction Types",
                    choices = oboler_data %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% tbl_vars)
    })
    
    
    varY = reactive({
        
        req(input$varSel)
        
        input$varSel
    })
    
    
    plotDiam = reactive({
        req(varY())
        oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref2.csv")
        DF <- data.frame(oboler_data)
       
        
        
        
        # graph by month:
       #ggplot(data = log,
             #  aes(Month)) +
            #stat_summary(fun.y = sum, # adds up all observations for the month
                    #     geom = "bar") + # or "line"
            #scale_x_date(
               # labels = date_format("%Y-%m"),
               # breaks = "1 month") # custom x-axis labels
        
        
        # graph by month:
        ggplot(DF,
               aes(Date,)) +
            stat_summary(fun.y = sum, # adds up all observations for the month
                         geom = "bar") + # or "line"
            scale_x_date(
                labels = date_format("%m"),
                breaks = "1 month") # custom x-axis labels
        
        
        ggplot(DF, aes_string(x="varY" ()))+
            geom_histogram(colour="darkgreen",fill="darkgreen")+
            labs(X="Date",y="Number of transactions",title = paste0(""))+
            
            
            theme_minimal()
        
    
            
            
            theme_minimal()
        
        
    })
    
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        plotDiam()
        
    })
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It would help if your example were minimal - we don't need all the extra Shiny code - and reproducible. All that's required to help solve your problem is `oboler_data` as plain text (or the output of `dput(oboler_data)`), or better still a link to the CSV file `ref2.csv`.

Comment: A couple of comments:  1) Your example should be the *minimal* amount of code required to reproduce the problem and should include sample data. 2) You're loading `plyr` after `dplyr` (both contain a function called `mutate()`.  3) You haven't created an object called `log` in the code provided - perhaps you meant `log <- oboler_data %>% ...` .

Comment: Assuming the error comes from this line `log <- log %>% mutate(Date = Date %>% as.character %>% ymd)` and assuming you mean: `log <- oboler_data %>% mutate(Date = Date %>% as.character %>% ymd)`, this code runs fine with me if `oboler_data` contains a column named `Date` and contains a string formatted as Y-m-d. I do note that you call `plyr` after `dplyr` while you code does not use `plyr`. There can be issues following from this, e.g. grouping will not work correctly. 
Can you show some of your data? E.g. through `dput(head(oboler_data))`?

Comment: structure(list(Month = structure(c(18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 
NA, NA), class = "Date"), Walkup = c(34, 54, 64, 54, NA, NA), 
    Zoom = c(44, 23, 33, 44, NA, NA), Email = c(12, 15, 9, 3, 
    NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))   What I got when I tried your suggestion was an error Error in as.character(.) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'   As I said it seems there is something about my data that mutate really won't process  Thanks again - I spent all day on this plus watching youtube tutorials and nothing worked

Comment: This part doesn't look right: `aes_string(x="varY" ())`, probably should just be `aes_string(x=varY())`

Comment: Also, not sure what youtube videos you watched, but this videos give a very good into to Shiny https://rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/

Comment: The Error in as.character(.) : cannot coerce type 'closure'...is because the sample data that you posted doesn't contain a column `Date`. It has a `Month` column and that column is already a date in YYYY-MM-DD format. I think you've just got some variables confused somewhere.

Comment: It's hard to say if that fixed it or not since the ggplot isn't functioning log$Month <- as.date(cut(log$date,
                         breaks = "month"))  plotDiam = reactive({
        req(varY())
        
        DF <- data.frame(oboler_data  
        ggplot(DF = log$Month,
               aes(varY(),month) +
            stat_summary(fun.y = sum, # adds up all observations for the month
                         geom = "bar") + # or "line"
            scale_x_date(
                labels = date_format("%Y-%m"),
                breaks = "1 month") # custom x-axis labels